# Java - read a file using executor service gives error 409

Tags: java, java-8, bufferedreader, executorservice, callable

How to read same file twice, in different tasks using executor service?

I used below sample code structure, but while reading same file simultaneously gives 409 error. How to resolve it?

```
//Sample code
ExecutorService ee = ExecutorService.FixedThread(2);

Callable<Object> C1 = ()-> {
InputStream in = new inputStream("https://server.com/file1");
BufferReader br = new BufferReader(in);
SysOut(br.lines);
                           }

Callable<Object> C2 = ()-> {
InputStream in = new inputStream("https://server.com/file1");
BufferReader br = new BufferReader(in);
SysOut(br.lines);
                           }

List task = new list();
task.add(c1);
task.add(c2);

ee.invokeAll(task);
ee.shutDown();
```

Each task individual works fine.

But when both the task are ran at same time, both tasks tries to access the same file and errors out wit 409 conflict error.

How to resolve it?

Note: I need to call same file simultaneously from different task.
I don't want to read the file once and store the content into list. Then use that list for further processing.

Comment: Where is the class inputStream defined?  Please post a [mvce].  thanks

Comment: That code will never work, it will be helpful to share some already tested code. Also: It seems you're dealing with HTTPS requests. That is very different than files, you will need an Http Client to deal with that.

Comment: You'll need an InputStream rather than an inputStream.

Comment: 409 Conflict: "Indicates that the request could not be processed because of conflict in the current state of the resource, such as an edit conflict between multiple simultaneous updates." But the code you've shown doesn't seem to update anything.

Comment: I have handled https authentication and i am able to read the file from a url if there is only one task. But as i am trying to read the same file simultaneously from two different task, it errors out at InputStream saying 409 error.  If i was trying to write something to that file simultaneously that 409 is understandable. But all i am trying to doing read same file at same time from different places.

Comment: Maybe the problem is on the server side? Did you try to read the file using curl or just opening it in two browsers?